i have a problem whit the expo router header
The problem occurs when I use router.navigate("/readView"). The readView does not display a header.
I use router.navigate in a component located in the tabs folder, and readView is in the app folder. This is the appLayout:
appLayout
I expect the header to be shown on the readView component. I have already tried changing the way of doing navigation, but it didn't work.
